# Current transducer - understanding of turns ratio connection

Tags: current-measurement, current-sensing

I'm using a [LEM LAH 25-NP](https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/lah_25-np.pdf) current sensor and I don't understand the recommended PCB connections in the table from the datasheet. I understand the first one, but what is with the second and third? What are the input and output pins?
[image]
So if there is a trace, I split the trace and put the sensor between the two traces to measure the current. How do I connect the pins with the traces? For 2 primary turns, do I use pins 2,3,6 as IN and pins 4 and 5 as OUT?

And what is with 3 primary turns? Are the input pins 2,6 and the output pins 3,5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably missed this little picture of the input wiring in the data sheet: -

[image]

It should make sense now.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?